# Export SQL Table to CSV with Custom Header (Change in Header Name)

Tags: sql, sql-server

TABLE-A

```
Client_Code   Client_Name   POST_HC_STK
123              Sam           100
456              Lily          500
568              Maria         200
789              Champ         300
```

Want Table output as under in CSV File

```
Client Code  Client Name    Post Haircut Stock
123              Sam           100
456              Lily          500
568              Maria         200
789              Champ         300
```

How to export Table-A with a change in column header into a CSV?

Comment: Hint:  `as` is used to assign column names.

Comment: You mean to only change column name in CSV ?

Comment: Is there any Code/Scrip/Query which can use to Export output in to Csv File?

Answer (score 3):

Simply write a select where you give your columnnames another ALIAS.

You can use it 2 ways.

> 1. You can export to CSV though your database in Management Studio
> 2. You can add it as OLE DB Source in SSIS and then add a flat file destination which points to a CSV File.

**SQL Query**

```
SELECT 
Client_Code as [Client Code]
,Client_Name as [Client Name]
,POST_HC_STK as [Post Haircut Stock]
FROM TableA
```

You can also write it like this - Which in my opinon is easier to read:

```
SELECT 
[Client Code]        = Client_Code,
[Client Name]        = Client_Name,
[Post Haircut Stock] = POST_HC_STK
FROM TableA
```